# running dll method Javafx

Tags: javafx, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror, native-methods

I have C program (Dll) which I can call from Java using JNI. I want to use Javafx for the interface so I made a java class to call the dll. I am able to load the dll but I cannot call the method. The error message it gives me is

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
mark1.Small_test.tester(DDDLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;DDD)[D
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

I have used the same Dll and it works if I call with normal java. I am using netbeans for JavaFX. I have been stuck with this problem for a week. Any help is greatly appreciated.