# Running a dll from JavaFX application

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, javafx-8, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have created a dll using C++ which i want to call from JavaFX. I have tried calling from Java it worked fine but when trying to call from JavaFX exception comes.

**Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**

This issue was asked earlier also can be refered [running dll method Javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10339570/6592403)
But there was no comment on the same.

Please help with the above issue. How to call a dll from JavaFX application.

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because there is nothing special when using JavaFX. Maybe some path or library is missing inside your javafx classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put your library on LD_LIBRARY_PATH or PATH. You can also use -Djava.library.path while running Java.

Take a look here, for very basic sample: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/